# An unknown glassware piece from our cupboard

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, equipment

We have multiple of these. It is a small glass funnel with splits into 3 spouts from it. Now, we are thinking it might be similar to a cow receiver, however, I have never seen one this small or delicate. It's 11cm in length.

We have put 3 test tubes underneath and ran water through and it does appear to distribute it relatively evenly.

What could it be?

[image]

Comment: Trident harpoon for glass fish? ;-)

Comment: Why does this post have closure votes as homework? If I search google for this image I get results for glass bottles, which is certainly not what is expected.

Comment: We have currently been calling it a funnel fork.... but I really have a feeling that isn't what its called!

Comment: It might be a cold finger to collect up to three fraction, fitting distillation of a micro amount (mg scale) of a single compound (head, x, tail).

Comment: My best guess is a "pis de vache" (i.e. "cow's udder" in French) which is used in distillation to collect several parts of the distillate. Though it is generally more useful during vacuum distillations, which is not the case here. See picture https://www.chemscience.com/categorie-produits.html?cat_id=249

Comment: Mad idea: if the "funnel like" ending fits in a chromatographic column, and if the tiny ends keep it anchored to the opening, maybe a normal funnel can be placed between the (so strangely bent) tiny arms, and the whole thing could serve as a kinky funnel adapter for chromatography .-.